# Calculate the volume of the solid bounded by the region

Tags: calculus, integration

Using spherical co-ordinates, find the volume of the solid region bounded above by the cone $z^2=3(x^2+y^2), z\geq 0$ and bounded below by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4.$

I tried in the following way:
$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/6} \int_{0}^{2} \rho^2 \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta$

$ \displaystyle = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/6} \left[\cfrac{\rho^3}{3}\right]_0^2 \sin\phi \ d\phi \ d\theta$

$ \displaystyle  = \cfrac{8}{3} \int_0^{2\pi} \left[- \cos \phi\right]_0^{\pi/4} \ d\theta$

$ \displaystyle  = \cfrac{16\pi}{3} \left(1 - \cfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right) $

Is my solution is correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I am getting problems in finding limits of the integration.

Comment: Your comment does not add anything to your post. Please again: [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): "include *your work* and thoughts on the problem".

Comment: I have added my solution.Just wanted to know this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you said 'get the limits of the integration...', the volume is finite.
$$I=\iint_{D}\left(\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}-\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2)}\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$
Here $D$ is the $xy$-region determined the intersection. It should be easy, I left it to you.

> When $\sqrt{4-r^2}=\sqrt{3r^2}$, the upper bound of $r$ is $1$. So$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{0}^{1}(\sqrt{4-r^2}-\sqrt{3r^2})r\mathrm{d}r=\frac{16\pi}{3}-\frac{8\sqrt{3}\pi}{3}$$

EDITED:
I misunderstood your meaning, the result should be volume of ball substracts $I$.
$$\frac{32\pi}{3}-I$$

Comment: $I=\frac{16\pi}{3}-\frac{8\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Yes, it is answer. Your solution is correct.

Comment: 1) The OP wanted to use spherical coordinates, which are more convenient for his problem. 2) Your $I$ does not at all represent the volume of his solid, which is bounded *above* by the cone and "below" by the sphere.

Comment: @AnneBauval I see, I will make a substraction to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not correct because the interval for $\phi$ is not $[0,\pi/6]$ but $[\pi/6,\pi].$ The answer is therefore:
$$V=\frac{16\pi}3\left[-\cos\phi\right]_{\pi/6}^\pi=\frac{16\pi}3\left(1+\frac{\sqrt3}2\right).$$
Note that the cone bounds your solid above, but the sphere does not bound it "below": rather "around". If you meant the other way round, the answer is of course
$$\frac43\pi2^3-V=\frac{32\pi}3-V=\frac{16\pi}3\left(1-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right).$$